# PhoneGap cannot run javac yet is is definitely on PATH

Tags: java, cordova

I've just installed PhoneGap but I have run into an issue when trying to run a build command

```
phonegap build android
```

I get an error as follows:

[image: PhoneGap build error]

It says that JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly and shows the path to the JRE yet you can see that JAVA_HOME is actually set to the bin folder of the JDK.

I have made sure that android sdk, jdk and ant are all on the path.

I can run javac from the command line myself without any problems, it's just PhoneGap which can't seem to find it for some reason.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `\bin` from the path, as `JAVA_HOME` should point to the JDK installation itself.

To keep `java`, `javac` and such as usable commands, add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the path.